# What is the proper way to install the latest version of Go on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, golang

This question might be overly simple, but I just want to make sure I'm not falling into some anti-pattern regarding package installation.

I found the [official installation instructions](https://golang.org/doc/install); however since what's available is a tarball and I already have the `golang-go` package installed via `apt`, should I simply remove golang-go, or what?

If I leave `golang-go` in place and just unpack the tarball according to the instructions, then the older version of `go` (in `/usr/bin/go`) is still first in my PATH lookup, so this doesn't seem to be a workable option.

Is there any drawback to uninstalling `golang-go` and just using the tarball only (as per those instructions)?